# Stripping out unwanted characters from a list of strings

Tags: python, list, strip

I have a list of strings called `file_contents`.
Each item in the list is proceeded by a number in this format: #1. #2. etc..
I want to strip those from each item in the list.

```
for item in range(len(file_contents)):
    file_contents[item].lstrip('#' + [item] + ". ")
```

So, I want to turn `"#1. Apples"` into `"Apples"`.

Any suggestions?

When I run this, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

This is the entire method I'm defining:

```
def read_from_file(self, filename):
        """Checks if file exists, if it does, reads it in and creates new List object."""
        file_contents = []
        fileExists = os.path.isfile(filename)
        if not fileExists:
            print(filename, "does not exist.")
        else:
            with open(filename) as file:
                file_contents = [line.strip() for line in file]

        for item in range(len(file_contents)):
            file_contents[item] = file_contents[item].lstrip('#' + str(item) + ". ")

        list_name = file_contents[0]
        list_contents = []
        for item in file_contents:
            if item in list_name:
                continue
            else:
                list_contents.append(item)

        new_list = List(list_name)
        new_list.contents = list_contents

        return new_list
```

Comment: You'd get a better answer if you showed more code. The fact that your variable name is `file_contents` suggests you could be opening the file and iterating over it directly, for instance, and the `range(len(file_contents))` anti-pattern could definitely be avoided here.

Comment: I figured out from a previously deleted comment from another user that my issue was with the [item] portion of my lstrip() argument.

Answer (score 4):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) are a good fit here:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'#\d+\.\s*')
new_contents = [pattern.sub('', item) for item in file_contents]
```

I'd recommend reading the doc link to see how regex works, but a brief explanation of the pattern:

- `#` - look for the `#` character
- `\d+` - followed by one or more digits
- `\.` - then a dot character
- `\s*` - then any amount of whitespace

`re.sub` looks for that pattern and then replaces it with `''`, an empty string - thus chopping it off.

You're also vastly misunderstanding how `lstrip` and Python syntax in general works:

1. it doesn't modify the string you call it on, it returns a new string.
2. `[item]` would just be `[0]`, `[1]`, etc., which is why you can't concatenate it to strings. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve there.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant to do was

```
stripped_contents = []
with open('test.data') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        strip = '#' + str(i + 1) + ". "
        stripped_line = line.lstrip(strip)
        stripped_contents.append(stripped_line)

print stripped_contents
```

i.e. You need to convert item into a string instead of a list. Plus since it starts at 0 you need item + 1.

Another solution could be

```
stripped_contents = []
with open('test.data') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        start_pos = len('#' + str(i + 1) + ". ")
        stripped_line = line[start_pos:]
        stripped_contents.append(stripped_line)

print stripped_contents
```

A Regular Expression will also work. But feels over complex for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any want to strip from the left pass all the characters to lstrip:

```
def read_from_file(self, filename):
        """Checks if file exists, if it does, reads it in and creates new List object."""
        file_contents = []
        fileExists = os.path.isfile(filename)
        if not fileExists:
            return (filename, "does not exist.")
        with open(filename) as file:
            file_contents = [line.lstrip("0123456789.").strip() for line in file]
```

You are removing newlines so you can simply call strip after which will remove the newline and the leading space:

```
In [14]: "#123. 1foo".lstrip("0123456789#.").strip()
Out[14]: '1foo'
```